# How to access the latest version of Delta table as Integer?

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

Can someone let me know to convert the following from a Dataframe to an InterType()

```
df = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1').history().select(max(col("version")).alias("version"))
```

I have tried the following

```
result = df.collect()[0]

result2  = df.withColumn("version",df.version.cast('integer'))
```

But with no luck

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table already exist:

```
dftemp = spark.sql("DESCRIBE history table1 limit 1").collect()
verno = int(dftemp[0][0])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
import pyspark.sql.functions

dt = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1')
latest_version = int(dt.history().select(max(col("version"))).collect()[0][0])
```

Comment: Hi @Jacek, thanks for reaching. This worked perfectly. P.S. I love your book.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I needed to add collect() to the dataframe.

```
df = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/mnt/lake/BASE/SQLClassification/cdcTest/dbo/cdcmergetest/1').history().select(max(col("version")).alias("version")).collect()
```

And then simply strip out the 0

```
df = df[0][0]
```

Comment: OK, I thought my solution worked but it was a false positive. I still need help